# Why is Method requiring only second parameter "argument"?

Tags: swift

I have the following method inside a `User` Class:

```
func Login(username: String, password: String) -> String
{
    return "Login Success";
}
```

Why on Earth it only works calling it if I specify the second parameter "label"(not sure what it is called)?

```
var loginReturn = user.Login("aa", password: "zz");
```

iIf I do the following I got error:

```
var loginReturn = user.Login("aa", "zz");
```

I'm not happy with Swift.

Comment: In Swift, t's generally **1)** bad syntax manners to  start a function name with a capital latter, **2)**  bad syntax manners to start a `Class` or `Struct` name with a lower-cased letter.

Comment: One of the keys of swift is its continuation of the objective c practice of including parameter names in calling sequences for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Functions in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

> Function parameters have both an external parameter name and a local parameter name. An external parameter name is used to label arguments passed to a function call. A local parameter name is used in the implementation of the function.
>   (...)
>   By default, the first parameter omits its external name, and the second and subsequent parameters use their local name as their external name.
>   (...)
>
> **Omitting External Parameter Names**
>
> If you do not want to use an external name for the second or subsequent parameters of a function, write an underscore (_) instead of an explicit external name for that parameter.

I recommend you to read the whole chapter, it should clear up your confusion.

Also note that the external parameter names are technically a part of the function/method name.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it like this:

```
func Login(username: String, _ password: String) -> String
{
    return "Login Success";
}
```

For every method parameter you can define "inner" and "outer" parameters which will define the final look of the methods call.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a function that has two parameters, you must list the name of the parameters after the first one if they have a name. With the current way you've written your function...

**This Code Works**

```
var loginReturn = login("aa", password: "zz")
```

**And This Code Fails**

```
var loginReturn = login("aa", "zz")
```